# visual studio not inputting URL into browser after driver.get(URL) because 'URL must be a string'

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Inputting the code below in Visual Studio, typing "node index.js" into the Terminal Output gives me:

"WebDriverError: unknown error: 'url' must be a string"

-have tried just using driver.get(URL); and typing into the Terminal Output "Set URL=http://port-80-6p76k7hj7t.treehouse-app.com/ node index.js" which returns an error message of "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'index.js'"

-have tried \ and // for the URL

This is the code that i'm using:

```
require('chromedriver'); 
const selenium = require('selenium-webdriver'); 
const By = selenium.By;
const driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
driver.get("https://port-80-6p76k7hj7t.treehouse-app.com/");
const locators = { inviteeForm: By.id("registrar"), inviteeNameField: By.name("name") };
function addInvitee(name) { driver.findElement(locators.inviteeNameField).sendKeys(name); driver.findElement(locators.inviteeForm).sub(); }

add invitee("Kevin Smith");
add invitee("Joe Smith");
```

Error i'm getting is:

```
[ERROR] node : C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2626
[ERROR] At line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + node index.js
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\users\kevin....promise.js:2626:String) [], RemoteException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]         throw error;
[ERROR]         ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] WebDriverError: unknown error: 'url' must be a string
[ERROR]   (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
[ERROR]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
[ERROR]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
[ERROR]     at parseHttpResponse (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
[ERROR]     at doSend.then.response (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
[ERROR]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(undefined)
[ERROR]     at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
[ERROR]     at Navigation.to (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1133:25)
[ERROR]     at thenableWebDriverProxy.get (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:988:28)
[ERROR]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\users\kevin.yu\selenium-basics\node_modules\index.js:12:8)
[ERROR]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
[ERROR]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
[ERROR]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
[ERROR]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
[ERROR]
```

I am permanently stuck, please send help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: putting in the Terminal Output: Set URL=http://port-80-6p76k7hj7t.treehouse-app.com/ node index.js --- gives me a "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'index.js'

Comment: I don't see in your code where `URL` is defined from `driver.get(URL);`. Are you missing some code or is that the issue?

Comment: I tried defining the URL through multiple options such as const URL = "https://port...." or driver.get("https://port...") and in the original post I put the URL in the terminal output as set URL = https://port.... node index.js

Comment: OK. Edit your question and post a complete [mcve] and the resulting error for that code. Right now it looks like you didn't define `URL` which would cause the issue you are referring to.